# transparent labels on mapserver using a mapfile

Tags: opacity, watermark, mapserver

i'm trying to add a watermark layer in my mapfile with a DEFAULT layer:

```
  LAYER
  OPACITY 20
  NAME "copyright"                   
  METADATA
    "wms_title"     "copyright"
  END
  STATUS DEFAULT
  TYPE ANNOTATION

  TRANSFORM ll 
  FEATURE
    POINTS
      220 -220 
    END
    TEXT "Sample Image" 
  END
  CLASS
    LABEL 
      FONT "ARIAL"
      TYPE TRUETYPE
      SIZE 30
      BUFFER 1
      COLOR 60 60 60
      FORCE TRUE
      ANGLE 40
    END
  END
  UNITS PIXELS 
END
```

but it seems that the OPACITY is not working, cause it doesn't change anything. Is it possible to set the OPACITY for labels? what am i doing wrong?

Thnx in advance

Comment: this is a mapfile used by the mapserver to create an image.. i'm using python and django to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. no.. apparently you can't change the opacity of labels in map server. Or at least not in this version

Follow this link for further reference: [Add OPACITY support for LABEL rendering](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/ticket/3033)